# Where are good sources of information on current tactics that are used in cyber attacks?

Tags: professional-education

I got hired in the cyber security field and it's a break-in for me. I have many years in the IT field so I am building right off of that.

My job requires knowledge of common attack vectors/signatures, recognition of a kill chain, isolation, remediation, and research. Basic CND type stuff.

One thing I am curious about is where would a cyber defender go to learn about zero-day exploits, cutting edge exploitation/attack routines, or anything else that a typical black hat (not a script kiddie) might know and use.

The emergent problem is that I don't want to make myself vulnerable or risk tipping others off to my presence while doing info mining. Most importantly, I don't want to risk damaging my integrity by being identified or associated with black hat groups.

I'm aware of the National Vulnerability Database but I'm concerned with the delta that exists between brand new attacks or exploits and known signatures that are archived there. The larger the delta between the two (the latency between the newest entries and the trailing edge of the latest exploits/attacks not yet captured), the more that info is deprecated. I want to minimize that delta by bridging the knowledge gap between what's available in the NVD and what has yet to be recorded and documented.

There are sites like Krebs On Security and the random articles found everywhere but are there any other useful repositories, forums/discussions, or sites that have been useful to farm that kind of information?

Comment: Check out SANS Institute.

Answer (score 8):

From -- https://attack.mitre.org/wiki/Main_Page

> Adversarial Tactics, Techniques, and Common Knowledge (ATT&CK™) is a
>   model and framework for describing the actions an adversary may take
>   while operating within an enterprise network. The model can be used to
>   better characterize and describe post-compromise adversary behavior.
>   It both expands the knowledge of network defenders and assists in
>   prioritizing network defense by detailing the post-compromise
>   (post-exploit and successful access) tactics, techniques, and
>   procedures (TTPs) advanced persistent threats (APT) use to execute
>   their objectives while operating inside a network.

The work is further expanded from red-team exercises in [The Fort Meade eXperiment (FMX)](http://www.asq509.org/ht/a/GetDocumentAction/i/124672).

---

For on-going cyber-offensive tradecraft, please see the following resources:

## Initial Entry-Point Access

---

### Conference Material

- irongeek.com
- infiltratecon.com
- blackhat.com
- gsec.hitb.org
- media.defcon.org
- recon.cx

### SANS

- pen-testing.sans.org
- https://lists.sans.org/mailman/listinfo/gpwn-list

### RecordedFuture

- https://www.recordedfuture.com/shared-poc-exploits/
- https://www.recordedfuture.com/russian-apt-toolkits/
- https://www.recordedfuture.com/top-vulnerabilities-2016/ -- https://www.recordedfuture.com/top-vulnerabilities-2015/
- https://www.recordedfuture.com/recent-ransomware-vulnerabilities/

### Research Labs

- labs.mwrinfosecurity.com
- immunityproducts.blogspot.com
- blog.trendmicro.com
- community.rapid7.com
- threatpost.com
- zscaler.com/blogs/research/
- code.google.com/p/google-security-research/ -- security.googleblog.com -- googleprojectzero.blogspot.com
- blog.coresecurity.com
- contextis.com/resources/blog/
- info.lastline.com/blog/
- fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/
- blog.skyboxsecurity.com
- nccgroup.trust/uk/our-research/ -- nccgroup.trust/globalassets/our-research/
- endgame.com/blog/
- labs.bluefrostsecurity.de
- signalsec.com/blog/
- talosintel.com
- blog.vectranetworks.com
- blog.checkpoint.com
- sekoia.fr/blog/
- payatu.com
- researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com
- symantec.com/connect/blogs/
- heimdalsecurity.com/blog/
- proofpoint.com/us/threat-insight/
- cgsec.co.uk
- expdev-kiuhnm.rhcloud.com
- keenlab.tencent.com
- blog.netspi.com
- exploresecurity.com
- silentbreaksecurity.com
- sensepost.com/blog/
- blackhillsinfosec.com
- utkusen.com/blog/english-articles
- blog.fortinet.com
- blogs.mcafee.com
- blog.morphisec.com
- srcincite.io
- blog.malwaretracker.com
- nakedsecurity.sophos.com

### Research Individuals

- shellntel.com
- cybersyndicates.com
- rotlogix.com
- malware.dontneedcoffee.com
- blog.skylined.nl
- blog.innerht.ml
- d.uijn.nl
- j00ru.vexillium.org
- blog.malerisch.net
- blog.malwareclipboard.com
- malwarejake.blogspot.com

---

## Access Expansion

This list probably includes some of the above, but these tend to focus on what to do after you already have access (i.e., Post-Exploitation techniques)

---

- harmj0y.net/blog/
- fuzzysecurity.com
- breakingmalware.com
- labofapenetrationtester.com
- crowdstrike.com/blog/
- blog.comae.io
- sixdub.net
- en.wooyun.io
- insinuator.net
- subt0x10.blogspot.com
- exploit-monday.com
- secinfodb.wordpress.com
- moyix.blogspot.com
- nightlionsecurity.com/blog/
- talosintelligence.com
- repret.wordpress.com
- astr0baby.wordpress.com
- woumn.wordpress.com
- travisaltman.com
- bhafsec.com
- crowdshield.com/blog.php
- labs.nettitude.com/blog/ -- nettitude.co.uk
- carnal0wnage.attackresearch.com
- countuponsecurity.com
- adsecurity.org
- clymb3r.wordpress.com
- enigma0x3.net
- kernelmode.info/forum/
- labs.portcullis.co.uk/blog/
- trustedsignal.blogspot.com
- marcoramilli.blogspot.com
- jumpespjump.blogspot.com
- hexacorn.com/blog/
- diablohorn.com
- toshellandback.com
- alex-ionescu.com
- thepcn3rd.blogspot.com
- blog.tanium.com
- trustedsec.com
- attactics.org
- shelliscoming.com
- hackerhurricane.blogspot.com
- leeholmes.com/blog/
- birendraraj0.blogspot.com
- dsinternals.com
- cyberarms.wordpress.com
- riosec.com
- insomniasec.com
- darkoperator.com
- buffered.io
- g-laurent.blogspot.com
- sternsecurity.com/blog/
- xlab.tencent.com
- bluescreenofjeff.com
- rvrsh3ll.net/blog/
- room362.com -- attackerkb.com -- cfdb.io
- securitynik.blogspot.com
- obscuresecurity.blogspot.com
- blog.didierstevens.com
- blog.varonis.com
- c0d3xpl0it.blogspot.com
- implicitdeny.org
- cutawaysecurity.com/blog/
- jimshaver.net
- cyberark.com/blog/
- binarydefense.com

Comment: *waves white flag* you win :)

Comment: Great list. community.rapid7.com redirects. Maybe it should be updated to https://blog.rapid7.com/

Comment: And cgsec.co.uk , expdev-kiuhnm.rhcloud.com , https://utkusen.com/blog/english-articles , rotlogix.com are dead links.

Comment: https://github.com/open-source-rs/OSRS-Taxonomies/blob/master/OSRS-OSINT-Source-Taxonomy/machinetag.json

Answer (score 4):

The very nature of a zero day exploit is that it is a previously unknown vulnerability. As such, people who have or know about zero days are not likely to be discussing them in public places. High value zero days are very expensive and are only used as a last resort. Zero day attack chains make for great news, but the reality is that they are only used if absolutely necessary and spear phishing can be extremely successful.

With that said here are some potentially useful resources for you.

- [2017 RAND paper on Zero Day exploits](http://www.rand.org/news/press/2017/03/09.html)
- [Verizon's 2016 Data Breach Investigations Report](http://www.verizonenterprise.com/verizon-insights-lab/dbir/2016/)
- [The Risky Business Podcast](https://risky.biz/) - Discusses InfoSec breaches / InfoSec emerging trends.
- [The Defensive Security Podcast](https://defensivesecurity.org/) - Discusses recent breaches and how they might have been avoided
- [The Hacking Team Hack "Case Study"](https://arstechnica.com/security/2016/04/how-hacking-team-got-hacked-phineas-phisher/)
- [Shadow Brokers NSA Dump](https://www.lawfareblog.com/very-bad-monday-nsa-0)

I could go on and on, but I think what you're *really* looking for is not available unless you thrust yourself into the underbelly of exploit development. There are organizations and individuals that create and sell exploits to entities for large sums of money so they are not easy to come by in the wild.